# allen-sdk:Visual Coding – Neuropixels How to know the name of recorded in anatomical structures

Tags: allen-sdk

How to know the full names of recorded anatomical structures in Visual Coding – Neuropixels — Allen SDK?

Best,
Nivaldo

I would like to know the full names of recorded anatomical structures in Visual Coding – Neuropixels — Allen SDK.